# Should an API specification include roles?

Tags: api-design

I'm considering options for specifying an API in a code library (e.g., XML or JSON) that can be consumed by various clients.

In addition to the standard kinds of input/output specifications, I'm considering including RBAC information to allow clients to make informed decisions about whether an API could be called in a particular execution context. For example, a consumer of the API may wish to suppress a link on a webpage if fulfilling that link requires a role the current user does not have.

I can see arguments for and against this:

Pro:

- Allows a single source of truth for the API "contract", including all relevant information about who can call it

  - Counterargument: API developers may be implementing in separate code libraries and repositories; they now have to update a centralized specification document in addition to their own repository.

Con:

- Combines concerns: resources and the roles allowed to access those resources are separate things.

  - Counterargument: The API specification is a use-case specifier, not just a resource specifier. It defines expected inputs and outputs for a use case, and error cases that result from an incorrect use case.

Comment: The con seems like an argument that isPermissionedForResource and getResource should be separate requests, not that they should be in separate APIs (assuming getResource is already required to do security checks). Also, how complex are the permissioning requirements for this API? For many apps it's as simple as "everyone can do X and Y, plus admins can do Z" so there's no need to do anything besides document that.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. The permission model is more complex than that: there will be various user roles ("main" users can access all resources associated with an account; various subsidiary/ancillary roles could only access certain subsets of those resources) and admin users who would be able to access data for any account. So it sounds like what your suggesting is to document the API structure independent of role, and require clients to validate access separately. That makes sense, although it increases the chattiness of a session somewhat.